# Position sticky not working in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my css:

```
.fixed-header {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 30px;
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div class="fixed-header">
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/spanish55" data-tabs="" data-width=""
                            data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true"
                            data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
       <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/spanish55" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a
                                    href="https://www.facebook.com/spanish55">Spanish55</a> 
       </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did it in my other projects before and never had a problem with that. I am using bootstrap 3.6 if this issue is due to the bootstrap version, i can't upgrade to the latest bootstrap version. Because all the website will be crushed if i upgrade it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```css
        .wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 1170px;
            padding: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .sticky {
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 20px;
            color: #000;
            text-align: left;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .box {
            height: 1800px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="fixed-header">
            <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/spanish55" data-tabs="" data-width=""
            data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true"
            data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
                <div class="box">
                    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/spanish55" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore sticky">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/spanish55" class="sticky">Spanish55</a> 
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```